# how to store validation rule on mongoDb and use these rules in C# model using Rule Engine

Tags: mongodb, document, rule-engine

how to store validation rule on mongoDb and apply these rules to model in C# using Rule Engine?

here i am applying rules on Student model using RuleEngine.

```
engine.For()                

                   .Setup(e => e.Name)
                       .MustNotBeNullOrEmpty()
                       .MustPassRule(new NameRule())

                   .Setup(e => e.Email)
                       .MustPassRule(new EmailRule())


                    .Setup(e => e.Mobile)
                        .MustPassRule(new MobileRule());
```

but in my case actually i want like  MustNotBeNullOrEmpty() and MustPassRule(new NameRule()) must come from Db and apply dynamically in case of Name of student as similar for all fields of Student model?

is there any solution for dynamically add Rules from DataBase(MongoDB)?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has dynamic schemas, so there is no way to enforce something like MustNotBeNullOrEmpty. However, you can rule out that a value is null or empty for a retrieved document by using a query like

```
db.yourColl.({$and:[
  {"fieldNotNullOrEmpty":{$exists:true}},
  {"fieldNotNullOrEmpty":{$ne:""}}
]})
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to design your rules to be represented in models that can be stored (in your case in mongoDB). For an example something like [this](http://wiki.flexrule.com/index.php?title=Validating_hierarchy) allows you to model validation rules in XML format. When you have a transferable objects that can be stored anywhere (file system, db, blob storage...), then are able to serialize the actual rule model into an intermediate form (XML, JSON...) and store those models back into your storage (e.g. mongoDB) and when you need you can load the models from your storage, deserialize and re-construct your rules model and then execute them.

The issue with your code example is that the modeling of rules are in fluent interface which can be used as a builder of your rule models not the actual model itself. Instead, separate your rule models from your builder component (the fluent interface). Then you are free to do what you need (e.g. storing in db) to do with your rule models.